Issues accessing sdf child component entity from system plugin
I am trying to obtain the entity of a child component. Here is the attempt:
virtual void Configure(const Entity &_entity, const std::shared_ptr<const sdf::Element> &_sdf, EntityComponentManager &_ecm, EventManager &_eventMgr) override 
{
   
    auto droneModelEntity =  EntityByComponents(components::Name("drone"));

}

And here is the error message:
error: ‘Name’ is not a member of ‘gz::sim::v7::components’
And here is the header file documentation of the used function (entityComponentManager.hh):
      /// \brief Get an entity which matches the value of all the given
      /// components. For example, the following will return the entity which
      /// has a name component equal to "name" and has a model component:
      ///
      ///  auto entity = EntityByComponents(components::Name("name"),
      ///    components::Model());
      ///
      /// \details Component type must have inequality operator.
      ///
      /// \param[in] _desiredComponents All the components which must match.
      /// \return Entity or kNullEntity if no entity has the exact components.
      public: template<typename ...ComponentTypeTs>
              Entity EntityByComponents(
                   const ComponentTypeTs &..._desiredComponents) const;

And lastly, this is my.world file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.8">
  <world name="sensor_world">
    <physics name="1ms" type="ignored">
      <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>1.0</real_time_factor>
      </physics>
    
      <plugin filename="libmy_plugin" name="gz::sim::systems::MyPlugin">
      </plugin>

      <gui fullscreen="0">

      <!-- 3D scene -->
      <plugin filename="MinimalScene" name="3D View">
        <gz-gui>
          <title>3D View</title>
          <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
          <property type="string" key="state">docked</property>
        </gz-gui>

        <engine>ogre2</engine>
        <scene>scene</scene>
        <ambient_light>0.4 0.4 0.4</ambient_light>
        <background_color>0.8 0.8 0.8</background_color>
        <camera_pose>-6 0 6 0 0.5 0</camera_pose>
        <camera_clip>
          <near>0.25</near>
          <far>25000</far>
        </camera_clip>
      </plugin>
    </gui>

    <model name='drone' canonical_link='base_link'>
      <static>true</static>
      <pose>-2 8 5 -1.57 0 0</pose>
      <frame name="lidar_frame" attached_to='base_link'>
        <pose>0 1 0 1.57 0 0</pose>
      </frame>

      <link name="base_link">
        <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
          <always_on>1</always_on>
          <update_rate>1</update_rate>
          <visualize>true</visualize>
          <topic>imu</topic>
        </sensor>
      </link>
    </model>

  </world>
</sdf>


Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Not sure about the error message, but I think you can use entitiesFromScopedName instead: see this example.
Alternatively, it could be an option to attach the plugin to your model instead of to the world, see this example. Then, in your plugin, you can check if you are effectively attached to a model, and access its elements from the sdf, see this example.
